# Code always returns isCC = false even for videos with closed captions - Apps Script

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

```
var caption = YouTube.Captions.list("snippet", "XPpsI8mWKmg")
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XPpsI8mWKmg

This video has closed captions. However, response always returns `isCC = false`. It happens with more videos as well. Can anyone tell me why?

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions

This is the response:

```
    [15-09-14 10:46:33:634 BST] {
kind=youtube#captionListResponse,
tag="jOXstHOM20qemPbHbyzf7ztZ7rI/pWn9PuYA4wHTOuk7gWrw_wkqaMg", 
items=[{snippet={lastUpdated=2015-04-22T15:19:44.401Z, 
        trackKind=ASR, isAutoSynced=false, 
        audioTrackType=unknown,
        isDraft=false, name=, 
        isEasyReader=false, 
        isLarge=false, 
        videoId=XPpsI8mWKmg, 
        language=en, isCC=false, 
        status=serving}, 

kind=youtube#caption,                              
etag="jOXstHOM20qemPbHbyzf7ztZ7rI/5QI7PZUUbbATmyKtvzGqv9-ylR0",          
id=5dp7OTjMUTyH2tf_kEhELNI2X9MpCov20brI5R-kAw4=}, 
    {snippet={
        lastUpdated=2015-04-22T15:12:54.185Z, 
        trackKind=standard, 
        isAutoSynced=false, 
        audioTrackType=unknown, 
        isDraft=false, 
        name=, 
        isEasyReader=false, 
        isLarge=false, 
        videoId=XPpsI8mWKmg, 
        language=en, 
        isCC=false, 
        status=serving}, 
kind=youtube#caption, 
etag="jOXstHOM20qemPbHbyzf7ztZ7rI/6A1s7QwGUJ_Jp39d-tidbyPR6t4", 
id=Q-Rh5crBiivJBgQyElc_gzhB8eK8y0V4}]}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked if that happens with other properties as well or only to isCC? Are there more properties that should have a value but dont? Like isLarge and others. That would narrow down the problem a little bit

Comment: @Víctor the rest seems fine, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to set closed captions for my own video and got the same result.

I believe that in the player, the "CC" you see is actually referring to subtitles. There's an important distinction between subtitles and closed captioning (see [here](http://www.rexie.com/Rexie/SDHandCC.html) and [here](http://www.3playmedia.com/2014/05/21/how-subtitles-deaf-hard-of-hearing-sdh-differ-from-closed-captions/)).

> Subtitles (or English Subtitles) is usually just a word-for-word
>   translation of the dialog into English words.

...

> CC usually also tells the viewer about sound effects or background
>   noises.  For example if you are watching a movie with explosions,
>   gunfire or other sounds that are important to the plot, CC will
>   usually display text that announces such sounds

Therefore, I believe `isCC` will only be `true` for videos that include this kind of captioning intended for people who might not be able to hear what's happening in the video, as opposed to just general captions that people can put onto their videos. I think that in almost all cases, only high quality, paid movies on YouTube will have these kinds of captions. In that sense, the `isCC` property works the way it's supposed to.

Comment: I was thinking the same way after a while having this problem. Thing is, the video I posted actually has information for the deaf or hard of hearing. Watch the first 12 seconds of the video and you'll see that. This implies isCC should return true.

Comment: Right, but I think the way subtitles/CC are currently set up, any captions a regular channel includes on their video will be considered "subtitles", and "true" closed captions will only be on videos that are full length, paid movies like you'd find [here](https://www.youtube.com/user/movies).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be in your syntax:

```
var caption = youtube.captions().list("snippet", "XPpsI8mWKmg").execute();
```

or maybe

```
var caption = youtube.Captions.list("snippet", "XPpsI8mWKmg").execute();
```

I dont have much experience with the youtube api but checking out the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/list) I found code above.

Comment: Thanks Victor. Unfortunately, that returns error:

TypeError: Cannot find function execute in object

Comment: Have you checked if you have access to any method that seems useful for the task at hand?